# CAS Single Sign Out - how is it working?

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

As per the documentation, there are two steps to enable single signout:

> 1. Add org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter as the first filter in filter chain.
> 2. Include org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener in web.xml

Can you explain how does it work when I call https://cas-server-host:8443/cas/logout?service=https://application-host:9080/cas/index.jsp?